# How to make border radius on small div appear the same as a larger div

Tags: html, css

I am creating a progress bar and my issue is: When the % progress is low (width: 0-5%), the border radius does not look the same as when it is larger (width: 5-100%).

In example 1 below, you can see the progress bar as it is intended to look.

In example 2 & 3, you can see how it looks when the width is low, causing the border-radius of the progress bar to not function the same as example 1.

I am considering I need a different way to "cut off" the progress, rather than just decreasing the width, but I wasn't able to come up with anything simple to do so. Anyone have a good idea on how to improve this code?

Note: I also have a secondary "ghost" progress bar which experiences the same issue and has complicated my attempts to keep it simple.

I have looked up some [progress bar examples](https://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/), but they experience the same issue. Some of the ones I have seen avoid the problem entirely by skipping straight from 0 to 5% but I do not want to do that.

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 0px solid white;
  /* border-radius issue */
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.progress-bar-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

/* some helper classes */

.ghost {
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.progress-percent {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.bg-blue {
  background: #0096FF;
}

.bg-grey {
  background: #E8E8E8;
}

.outer-container {
  margin-top: 16px
}
```

```html
<!-- example 1 -->
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-container bg-grey">
    <div class="progress-bar ghost bg-blue" style="width: 75%;">
    </div>
    <!-- variable width is above ~5% -->
    <div class="progress-bar bg-blue" style="width: 45%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- example 2 -->
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-container bg-grey">
    <div class="progress-bar ghost bg-blue" style="width: 45%">
    </div>
    <!-- variable width is below ~5% -->
    <div class="progress-bar bg-blue" style="width: 1%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- example 3 -->
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-container bg-grey">
    <div class="progress-bar ghost bg-blue" style="width: 45%">
    </div>
    <!-- variable width is below ~5% -->
    <div class="progress-bar bg-blue" style="width: 3%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1oynkcp/1/) with some extra hover text which is un-related to issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add `overflow: hidden;` to `.progress-bar`

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 0px solid white;
  /* border-radius issue */
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-bar-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

/* some helper classes */

.ghost {
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.progress-percent {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.bg-blue {
  background: #0096FF;
}

.bg-grey {
  background: #E8E8E8;
}

.outer-container {
  margin-top: 16px
}
```

```html
<!-- example 1 -->
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-container bg-grey">
    <div class="progress-bar ghost bg-blue" style="width: 75%;">
    </div>
    <!-- variable width is above ~5% -->
    <div class="progress-bar bg-blue" style="width: 45%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- example 2 -->
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-container bg-grey">
    <div class="progress-bar ghost bg-blue" style="width: 45%">
    </div>
    <!-- variable width is below ~5% -->
    <div class="progress-bar bg-blue" style="width: 1%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- example 3 -->
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-container bg-grey">
    <div class="progress-bar ghost bg-blue" style="width: 45%">
    </div>
    <!-- variable width is below ~5% -->
    <div class="progress-bar bg-blue" style="width: 3%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This loses the roundness of the end of your loading bar, but if you combine this with A Haworth's answer you get a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Doh! Thank you, this worked beautifully and I can combine with A Haworth's answer if I want to maintain the rounded edges.

Answer (score 2):

**Consider this question:** What does a 4px wide pill shape look like with 8px rounded corners?

It's a trick question because a 4px wide pill shape can not have rounded corners bigger than 2px.  CSS understands this so when you define rounded corners bigger than 1/2 of a shape's width, it automatically scales them down.

My preferred way to overcome things like this is to mask your loading bar.  This is where you put a shape over your loading bar that is the same color as the background to hide bits of it.

[image]

The nice thing about masking is that you can make your loading bar look however you want, not just rounded/square:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The border radius needs 'enough' pixels to play with.

This snippet sets a CSS variable --w instead of the actual width in the elements and then in CSS increases the width by 16px and moves them back 16px so there is a rounded look to even the smallest width.

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 0px solid white;
  /* border-radius issue */
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.progress-bar.bg-blue {
  width: calc(var(--w) + 16px);
  left: -16px;
}

.progress-bar-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}


/* some helper classes */

.ghost {
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.progress-percent {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.bg-blue {
  background: #0096FF;
}

.bg-grey {
  background: #E8E8E8;
}

.outer-container {
  margin-top: 16px
}
```

```html
<!-- example 1 -->
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-container bg-grey">
    <div class="progress-bar ghost bg-blue" style="--w: 75%;">
    </div>
    <!-- variable width is above ~5% -->
    <div class="progress-bar bg-blue" style="--w: 45%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- example 2 -->
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-container bg-grey">
    <div class="progress-bar ghost bg-blue" style="--w: 45%">
    </div>
    <!-- variable width is below ~5% -->
    <div class="progress-bar bg-blue" style="--w: 1%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- example 3 -->
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-container bg-grey">
    <div class="progress-bar ghost bg-blue" style="--w: 45%">
    </div>
    <!-- variable width is below ~5% -->
    <div class="progress-bar bg-blue" style="--w: 3%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use one div and two pseudo-elements. Have the pseudo-elements take up 100% of the width and then translate them by calculating their distance to the `right`, and finally hiding them by setting `overflow: hidden` on the div.

Use CSS variables to control the percentage of the pseudo-elements.

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.progress-bar,
.progress-bar::before,
.progress-bar::after {
  --progress-bar-height: 1rem;
  height: var(--progress-bar-height);
  border-radius: var(--progress-bar-height);  
}

.progress-bar::before {
  background-color: lightgreen;
   --x-displacement: calc(100% - var(--progress-1));
}

.progress-bar::after {
   background-color: blue;
   --x-displacement: calc(100% - var(--progress-2));
}

.progress-bar::before,
.progress-bar::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: var(--x-displacement);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar" style="--progress-1: 80%; --progress-2: 0%"></div>

<div class="progress-bar" style="--progress-1: 50%; --progress-2: 10%"></div>

<div class="progress-bar" style="--progress-1: 10%; --progress-2: 70%"></div>
```